# Agregar Formulario Dinamicamente PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario que guarda para (1)Empresa (N)Sucursales. El punto es que no se cómo hacer para añadir N cantidad de sucursales según el usuario.

A modo de ejemplo:

```html
<form action="../Logica/registrarResiduos.php" method="post" onsubmit="return verifOpt()">

<h2>6)A .DATOS DE EMPRESA:</h2>
<label>Razon Social: </label> <input type="text" id="txtRS" name="razonsocial" maxlength="50" required="required"/>

<h2>6)A .DATOS DE SUCURSAL:</h2>
<label>6)A.1. Domicilio: Calle:</label><input type="text" name="calle1" maxlength="50"  required="required"/>
```

En PHP uso `$_POST['razonsocial']` para el nombre de la empresa y `$_POST['calle1']` para la calle de la sucursal.

¿Cómo hago para que el usuario vaya agregando tantas sucursales como quiera? (sin tener que generar los campos con JavaScript y después tener que recorrer con PHP ya que el formulario es grande y me llevaría mucho trabajo hacer eso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar ajax para enviar los datos al server y guardar los datos de la sucursal, al guardar la sucursal podrías mostrar un alert con javascript informando que se ha guardado correctamente, una vez echo esto puedes seguir insertando datos las veces que quieras con el mismo form.

Te recomiendo que revises información sobre: **Aplicaciones de página única(SPA)** aquí un link: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: lo de ajax no lo había pensado, me interesa, voy a investigar al respecto. Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta marcala como solución a tu problema, así otros usuarios también pueden encontrarla útil.

Answer (score 0):

PHP es un lenguaje que corre en el servidor, de tal manera que lo que le mandas al usuario ya es la página final. Necesitarias hacerte una funcion con un lenguaje en cliente como JavaScript o bien, si no quieres, puedes hacerte una página intermedia que le preguntes el numero de sucursales que quiere meter y cuando le de a enviar le mandes una pagina con todos los campos hechos. De todas maneras, aunque tenga un gran numero de campos el formulario, la funcion solo escribiria un trozo de codigo sobre la zona que quieres del HTML.

Pero de todas maneras necesitas procesarlo en el servidor previamente si quisieras hacerlo solo con PHP.

Espero que te haya ayudado!